# How to run wxPython with the python.org installer on macOS 12.4 (Monterey)

Tags: python, macos

I want to install python from python.org and have it work with wxPython in a terminal on macOS:

- Install python 3.9.13 using the macOS 64-bit universal2 installer
- Install wxPython using pip - `pip3 install -U wxPython`
- Start python in a shell and try and fire up a wx app:

```
DB0837:~ andypiper$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
Python 3.9.13 (v3.9.13:6de2ca5339, May 17 2022, 11:37:23) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
>>> wx.App()
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac.
```

Please don't point me at brew or pyenv or anaconda or framework builds - I want the above combination to work, and it seems not to. The download from python.org **is** a framework build and if I run this from IDLE it works fine using the exact same version of python, so it feels like it must be some macOS security issue or shell/python interaction

Comment: does this help: [wxpython-this-program-needs-access-to-the-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531006/wxpython-this-program-needs-access-to-the-screen)

Comment: Literally no - that is the post I used to produce the demo program that doesn't work. Also note that pythonw no longer exists in python 3.9.x (not needed apparently) and the rest of the solutions involve anaconda - which I don't want. I want to get to the bottom of this specific scenario, not change it for a new scenario

Comment: How about this: https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/error-running-psychopy-from-code-on-mac-on-venv-python-needs-framework-python/24433

Comment: I think this is just saying "use a framework build" - which I am

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem on an existing codebase after upgrading to Monterey.

My app still worked when built with py2app, but not when running from the command line.

It seems like the underlying wxWidgets method `IsDisplayAvailable` started to fail, so I just removed the check.

It's in your site packages at `wx/core.py`, line 2183.

Change

```
   if not self.IsDisplayAvailable():
```

to

```
   if False:
```

and you are off to the races.

What can I say?  It's very dirty, but I'm working again.

Comment: Woah, that works! Outstanding

Comment: This works on my M1 using a Conda virtual environment.  I searched for hours.. and followed numerous posts.  This is the only one that works (for me)

Comment: Likewise, I've tried to get this working so many times, and I can't believe this actually works! I did find some places where I needed to edit my code. I got errors on some wxALIGN_RIGHT type options, but I can remove those and the app runs!